# Javascript select/deselect all checkboxes in a form

Tags: javascript, select, checkbox

I want to make a javascript select/deselect all checkbox.

Here is my script, but it does not work:

```
<form id="labels">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" id="select_all">
</form>
<script>
$('#select_all').click(function()
{
        if($("#select_all").is(':checked'))
        {
            $("form#labels input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', false);
        }else{
            $("form#labels input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', true);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `.change` event - and reference `this` - also, you can shorten this up quite a bit:

```
$('#select_all').change(function() {
    $("form#labels input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/om37znud/

Answer (score 1):

You should swap the `true` and `false` booleans.

```js
$('#select_all').click(function() {
  if($("#select_all").is(':checked')) {
    $("form#labels input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', true);
  }else{
    $("form#labels input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="labels">
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" id="select_all" />
</form>
```

Also it can be simplified to

```
$('#select_all').click(function(){
  $("#labels input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

```js
$('#select_all').click(function(){
  $("#labels input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="labels">
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" id="select_all" />
</form>
```